# Why echo $this->uri->segment(3) output is different then what i see in url

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i have url like that:

```
http://localhost/testproject/data/getData/幻想
```

And then in function getData i have that:

```
public function getData($title){
    echo $title;
}
```

And in output i see:

```
%E5%B9%BB%E6%83%B3
```

Same is if i try  $this->uri->segment(3).
Why is that so, and how to fix it? I also noticed that if i paste whole url here i get:

```
  http://localhost/testproject/data/getData/%E5%B9%BB%E6%83%B3
```

I'm realy at dead end here...

Btw. file is encoded in UTF8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this

site_url('data/getData/'.urlencode('幻想'));
```

On php end use this

```
$segment = $this->uri->segment(3);
$value = urldecode($segment);
```

See if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use urldecode look at this http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

because of spacial characters, white spaces.

try encode or decode your url to see correct one you can user urldecode() function or urlencode() depends on the way you want to display...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php